# How to build two detailViewControllers with UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

My UITableView include multitype data, one is showing some pictures and another is visiting website, so how do I implement?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Following approach

Use following table delegate method,and in this method check your data type is URL or Image according to these push particular View Controller.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    // check your data type

    if(Data type is URL)
    {
       From Here Push ViewController for URL
    } 

    if(DATA TYPE IS IMAGE)
    {
        From HERE push ViewController FOR Image
    }
}
```

**OR Another approach :**

1, Take one BOOL variable, set its value in following method, if it is URL set BOOL YES and if it is image set BOOL NO.

2, Check BOOL value and handle you subview in your detailViewController by hiding and Show it.